# Font style for page number for chapter in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, page-numbering

The page numbers in the ToC appear in different styles. For sections and subsections in normalsize and for the chapter in **bold** and slightly larger (I think). How can one change the fontsize/fonttype for the page number of a chapter entry in the ToC?

document style: book

live-tex LaTeX, from Ubuntu 11.4
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package offers you a series of commands to customize the ToC, LoF, and LoT. In your case, you can redefine `\cftchappagefont` to use `\normalfont` (and possibly a font size switch):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchappagefont{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}

\end{document}
```

Another option would be to redefine the command `\l@chapter` (as implemented in `book.cls`) which actually typesets the chapter entries in the ToC; in this case, the redefinition would imply using `\normalfont` just before the page number is typeset. Here's such a redefinition:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss\normalfont #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Of course, the `etoolbox` package makes this a lot shorter:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\hss}{\hss\normalfont}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Is is the only answer?

Comment: @Igor: no, it's not. I've added two more solutions.